# Record and plays multiple videos with Processing

Tags: video, processing, webcam

I am trying to set up the following using Processing:

- A person hit a/any key to start and end a recording in front of a web camera.
- While she/he is in front of the camera, doing the recording, he/she can see the looping recordings of the last three people before him/her.
- No need to worry about sound.
- It would be great to save all the videos, although it's not a priority.

So, code I have so far is like this:

```
import processing.video.*;

VideoExport videoExport;
boolean recording = false;

Capture theCap; 

Capture cam;

void setup() {
  size(400, 300);
  frameRate(30);

  String[] cameras = Capture.list();

  if (cameras.length == 0) {
    println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
    exit();
  } else {
    println("Available cameras:");
    for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
      println(cameras[i]);
    }

    // The camera can be initialized directly using an 
    // element from the array returned by list():
    cam = new Capture(this, cameras[3]);
    cam.start();  
  }

  println("Press R to toggle recording");

  videoExport = new VideoExport(this, "video.mp4");
}

void draw() {

  if (cam.available() == true) {
    cam.read();
  }
  image(cam, 0, 0);
  // The following does the same, and is faster when just drawing the image
  // without any additional resizing, transformations, or tint.
  //set(0, 0, cam);

  if(recording) {
    videoExport.saveFrame();
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
    recording = !recording;
    println("Recording is " + (recording ? "ON" : "OFF"));
  }
}
```

I've tried many different things, such as `videoExport`, as you seen above. What I have tried only saved the video by overwriting the previous file and could not update the video properly. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two main problems:

- You only ever write to a single video file, so you'll just replace whatever was there before.
- You never actually check for the user pressing the 'A' key, so you never increment which video you're saving to.

To fix both of these problems, you need to **add a variable that keeps track of which video index is being recorded** and then use that variable to save the video and play back previous recordings.

An example start would look like this:

```
import processing.video.*;

VideoExport videoExport;
boolean recording = false;

Capture theCap; 

Capture cam;

int index = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400, 300);
  frameRate(30);

  String[] cameras = Capture.list();

  if (cameras.length == 0) {
    println("There are no cameras available for capture.");
    exit();
  } else {
    println("Available cameras:");
    for (int i = 0; i < cameras.length; i++) {
      println(cameras[i]);
    }

    // The camera can be initialized directly using an 
    // element from the array returned by list():
    cam = new Capture(this, cameras[3]);
    cam.start();
  }

  println("Press R to toggle recording");

  videoExport = new VideoExport(this, "video" + index + ".mp4");
}

void draw() {

  if (cam.available() == true) {
    cam.read();
  }
  image(cam, 0, 0);
  // The following does the same, and is faster when just drawing the image
  // without any additional resizing, transformations, or tint.
  //set(0, 0, cam);

  if (recording) {
    videoExport.saveFrame();
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
    recording = !recording;
    println("Recording is " + (recording ? "ON" : "OFF"));
  } else   if (key == 'a' || key == 'A') {
    index++;
    videoExport = new VideoExport(this, "video" + index + ".mp4");
  }
}
```

Notice that all I did was add the `index` variable, and then incremented that variable in the `keyPressed()` function. Then I create a new `VideoExport` using that index, so I don't overwrite the existing file.

This has the benefit of saving every video to a separate file, so if you also want to play back the previous 3 videos, just play back `index-3`, `index-2`, and `index-1`.